# WordPress Methods

Tags: php, wordpress

Что возвращает метод `the_post_thumbnail()` в wordpress если указать изображение которое не существует?

Пробовал функции: **empty, isset, is_null.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. 
Проверку делаем через `has_post_thumbnail()` возвращает `true` если миниатюра есть то-есть код такой.

```
if(has_post_thumbnail()) 
{
    the_post_thumbnail();
} 
else 
{
    echo 'Данных нет!';
}
```

PS: Через другие способы результат был не очень хорош

Comment: Ответом не является, потому что не соответствует вопросу. Вопрос: "Что возвращает метод...?". Ответ: "Проверку делаем так".

Comment: @KAGGDesign изначально не внимательности взял правку в которой убиралась часть о проверке

Comment: Надо было или сразу вопрос поправить, пока не начали отвечать, или задать новый вопрос, на тему "как проверить"

Answer (score 0):

```
if(the_post_thumbnail() === NULL) {
   echo 'Данных нет!';
}
```

> Ничего - выводит на экран строку. Функция выводит на экран html код
>   картинки или пустое значение (null), если картинки не существует.

Comment: Не корректно работает

Comment: @СашаАдамов опишите конкретно проблему. Фраза "Не корректно работает" не дает не какой полезной информации

Comment: есть пост с картинкой
Вывелась и фраза 'Данных нет' и фотография

Comment: @СашаАдамов а не выводится эта функция где то 2 раза в коде?

Comment: Ну так 'if(the_post_thumbnail() === NULL) {
   echo 'Данных нет!';
} 
else { the_post_thumbnail(); }

Comment: Если нет миниатюры, то на экран выводится не null, а пустая строка.

Answer (score 0):

Уточнение: the_post_thumbnail() это не метод класса, а функция. Вот ее код:

```
function the_post_thumbnail( $size = 'post-thumbnail', $attr = '' ) {
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( null, $size, $attr );
}
```

Вот код get_the_post_thumbnail():

```
function get_the_post_thumbnail( $post = null, $size = 'post-thumbnail', $attr = '' ) {
    $post = get_post( $post );
    if ( ! $post ) {
        return '';
    }
    $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post );

    /**
     * Filters the post thumbnail size.
     *
     * @since 2.9.0
     *
     * @param string|array $size The post thumbnail size. Image size or array of width and height
     *                           values (in that order). Default 'post-thumbnail'.
     */
    $size = apply_filters( 'post_thumbnail_size', $size );

    if ( $post_thumbnail_id ) {

        /**
         * Fires before fetching the post thumbnail HTML.
         *
         * Provides "just in time" filtering of all filters in wp_get_attachment_image().
         *
         * @since 2.9.0
         *
         * @param int          $post_id           The post ID.
         * @param string       $post_thumbnail_id The post thumbnail ID.
         * @param string|array $size              The post thumbnail size. Image size or array of width
         *                                        and height values (in that order). Default 'post-thumbnail'.
         */
        do_action( 'begin_fetch_post_thumbnail_html', $post->ID, $post_thumbnail_id, $size );
        if ( in_the_loop() )
            update_post_thumbnail_cache();
        $html = wp_get_attachment_image( $post_thumbnail_id, $size, false, $attr );

        /**
         * Fires after fetching the post thumbnail HTML.
         *
         * @since 2.9.0
         *
         * @param int          $post_id           The post ID.
         * @param string       $post_thumbnail_id The post thumbnail ID.
         * @param string|array $size              The post thumbnail size. Image size or array of width
         *                                        and height values (in that order). Default 'post-thumbnail'.
         */
        do_action( 'end_fetch_post_thumbnail_html', $post->ID, $post_thumbnail_id, $size );

    } else {
        $html = '';
    }
    /**
     * Filters the post thumbnail HTML.
     *
     * @since 2.9.0
     *
     * @param string       $html              The post thumbnail HTML.
     * @param int          $post_id           The post ID.
     * @param string       $post_thumbnail_id The post thumbnail ID.
     * @param string|array $size              The post thumbnail size. Image size or array of width and height
     *                                        values (in that order). Default 'post-thumbnail'.
     * @param string       $attr              Query string of attributes.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'post_thumbnail_html', $html, $post->ID, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr );
}
```

Как видим, если не найден пост, или у него нет изображения, функция возвращает пустую строку, которая потом и выводится на экран.

Сама функция the_post_thumbnail() не возвращает ничего.

Comment: То есть проверка через !empty() ?

Comment: Это проверка ничего не даст. Функция the_post_thumbnail() ничего не возвращает. Никогда.

Comment: то-есть? как проверять тогда

Comment: $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbmail(); if ( '' !== $thumbnail ) { echo $thumbnail; } else { echo 'Данных нет!'; }